# HangFire Queued Emails "Succeeding" But not Sending

Tags: c#, html, smtp, hangfire, system.web

I can send emails using the method when not using hangfire.

When the method is called from hangfire it is shown as succeeded but the email doesnt send.

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Email(Subject),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    );
```

```
public void Email(string Subject)
{
    try
    {
        //Initialize WebMail
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "relay.example.com";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
        WebMail.SmtpUseDefaultCredentials = false;
        WebMail.UserName = "xxxx";
        WebMail.Password = "xxxx";
        WebMail.From = "\"Reports\" <Reports@example.com>";

        //Send Email
        WebMail.Send(to: "client@example.com",
            subject: Subject,
            body: "Test Email"
        );
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

The username, password, and relay service have been removed for security as has the actual email addresses.

I have gone and removed the try/catch blocks to see if there are any errors produced.
Normally, It succeeds as before but occasionally it will throw the following error.

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.AspNetRequestScopeStorageProvider.get_RequestScopeInternal()
at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.AspNetRequestScopeStorageProvider.get_CurrentScope()
at System.Web.Helpers.WebMail.set_SmtpServer(String value)
at Email(String Subject)
```

I have then attempted the version that allows for type passing.

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule<WebMail>(
        () => Email(Subject),
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        );
```

However that throws a compiler error about using a static type.

Thanks for any help guys.

EDIT:

Still open to better options.  However I did find a cheeky work around.  I was able to get this to work by creating a method that fires a post request to a page to actually send the email.  Whereas Hangfire just activates the post request.

EDIT: NVM workaround was a false positive due to an extra line that was left in from testing

Comment: You should almost never put an empty catch block in your code. Remove it from your actual code, and remove it from your question. Also, why are you using the WebMail class instead of [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Please for the love of god leave and answer you are a life saver.

Comment: I have removed the try catch in actual code i had just left it in the question.  And I didn't believe the Webmail would have been a problem as internally it uses SmtpClient.

Comment: WebMail is part of System.Web.Helpers, which is for ASP.NET Web Pages. Not intended for use as a general SMTP client or use outside of Web Pages.

Comment: Once again thank you. I would love to give you rep for the assistance.  So if you could leave an answer so I could accept it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebMail class is intended for usage in ASP.NET Web Pages context. When used outside that context it probably doesn't have everything it needs, and thus you will get a NullReferenceException.

Instead, use the [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class.