# ASP.NET null refence exception in View Renderer

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have got Null reference exception when I try render razor view.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.AspNetRequestScopeStorageProvider.get_RequestScopeInternal()
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.AspNetRequestScopeStorageProvider.get_CurrentScope()
   at System.Web.WebPages.Scope.ScopeStorage.get_CurrentScope()
   at System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.<Start>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.get_Scope()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.get_UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(String name, ModelMetadata metadata)
```

I have found the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917877/hangfire-queued-emails-succeeding-but-not-sending) , but not found the fix.

Here is code of render:

```
public string RenderView(string nameFile, object model)
{
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary
    {
        Model = model
    };
    var url = HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() : "http://localhost";
    
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext
    {
        HttpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, url, null), new HttpResponse(null))),
        RouteData = new RouteData()
        {
            Values = { { "controller", "empty" }, { "action", "empty" } },
            DataTokens = { { "controller", "empty" }, { "action", "empty" } }
        },

    };
    var page = new RazorView(controllerContext, nameFile, "", true, new[] { "cshtml" });
    var stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
    {
        view.Render(new ViewContext(controllerContext, page, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), writer), writer);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I understand that rendering outside ASP.NET Pages is not create ScopeStorage, but I can't create it manually and can't skip calling it.